# Magento newsletter subscription form isn't subscribing user

Tags: php, magento, newsletter

I have a newsletter sign up form on my site which uses the following code:

```
<form action="http://kitronik.absolute-staging.co.uk/src/trunk/newsletter/subscriber/new/" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="form-subscribe-header">
            <label for="newsletter">Sign up to our newsletter to get the latest product and company information:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
           <input type="text" name="newsletter_name" id="newsletter_name" placeholder="Name" title="Name" class="input-text required-entry">
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
           <input type="text" name="newsletter_email" id="newsletter_email" placeholder="Email" title="Email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email">
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit" title="Sign Up" class="button"><span><span>Sign Up</span></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The form appears to submit, and I get no errors but there is no success/fail message and I can't see any record of the subscription in the database. Any ideas? Might I have missed a config setting somewhere?

Comment: You should share your controller action...

Comment: check your system.log or exception.log in var/log folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    <div class="input-box">
       <input type="text" name="newsletter_email" id="newsletter_email" placeholder="Email" title="Email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email">
    </div>
```

to

```
    <div class="input-box">
       <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter_email" placeholder="Email" title="Email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email">
    </div>
```

Name should be 'email' if you use standard Magento controller. No need in newsletter_name input then - native controller will not get data from it. If you want to use input name "newsletter_email" and use "newsletter_name" somehow then you should create your own controller.

Comment: Thanks @magalter - worked perfectly. I still need to get it to store the user's name but the email address is being subscribed properly.

Comment: You should create your own controller then and add some code to set name there.